# Update a string who was init with values returned from a function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to update a string who was initialized with a value returned from a function?

Here is a example of what I'm speaking:

```
var level = 1,
    returnLevel = function() {
        return level;
    },
    str = 'level: ' + returnLevel();

level = 2;

// how to update the var str without doing 'level:' + level?
```

EDIT: real code, since it was asked (I minified this code a lot):

```
function returnPrice(what) {
    return g.items[what].baseCost;
};

g.items = {
    'item-1': {
        baseCost: 100
    },
    'item-2': {
        baseCost: 1000
    },
    'item-3': {
        baseCost: 5000
    }
};

g.console.commands = [
    {
        name: 'buy',
        desc: 'command desc',
        commands: [
            {
                name: 'buy item',
                desc: 'buy specified item',
                customDesc: [
                    'test desc $' + returnPrice('item-1') + '.',
                    'test desc $' + returnPrice('item-2') + '.',
                    'test desc $' + returnPrice('item-3') + '.'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: You can't like that. You could write a function which updates the `level` value and at the same time updates `str` but you can't just change a variables' value and have it automatically update another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use `str` as a function and implement a `toString` method for calling the actual value without parenthesis.

```js
var level = 1,
    returnLevel = function () {
        return level;
    },
    str = function () {
        function f() { }
        f.toString = function () {
            return 'level: ' + returnLevel();
        }
        return f;
    }();

console.log(str);
level = 2;
console.log(str);
```

Comment: `str` will still be a function and any place not calling `toString` will fail on this, e.g. any code using `typeof` to determine what the parameter is. Also my firefox's `console.log` sais `function f()` and my chrome's `function level: 1`

Comment: yes, `str` is a function, not a string. but it behave like a string in a string expecting environment. the vendor specific implementation of `console` is not part of the language standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that like that; you might want to go with something like this instead:

```
var returnString = function(level) {
        return 'level: ' + level;
    },
    str = returnString(1);
console.log(str);
str = returnString(2);
console.log(str);

// also possible:
console.log(returnString(3));
```

Comment: Well, the problem is I got an array full of strings that got returned values from functions. I can't do it like this, I just wanted to know if it was possible to 'track' the returned value (just returned value, not whole string) from a function in a string, so I could update it when needed.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

```js
//The closure is just to make 'level' private
let obj = (() => {
  let level = 0;
  return {
    get levelString() { return "level: " + level; },
    set level(val) { level = val; }
  };
})();

console.log(`Before: '${obj.levelString}'`);
obj.level = 4;
console.log(`After: '${obj.levelString}'`);
```

Edit: if you downvote, at least give an explanation why.